# Android fragment exists from previous state and cannot be removed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following setup which is quite common: in landscape mode I have 2 fragments - A and B. In portrait mode I have only fragment A. I tried to detect if I am in second setup mode by just a simple check:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_b) == null
```

This was working fine until I was in 2 fragment mode and rotating the device to 1 fragment mode - after that the manager was finding the fragment B and **not** returning `null`. I believe the fragment manager was somehow saving and loading its state from previous setup. The first question - why is this working this way and what can I do with it?

Second question - I tried to remove the fragment but was not able to do that. Here how I tried:

```
Fragment f = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.frag_b);
manager.beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
f = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.frag_b); // still there
```

I guess `remove()` didn't work since it was not added using `add()` but rather loaded from **previous state xml**. Is there a way to remove a fragment from manager in this case?

P.S. The solution for me will be to have another way of detection in which mode I am. I already have this, just need to know how it works for better understanding of fragments and their behavior.

Comment: Do you have those 2 fragments defined in activitie's xml file?

Comment: Yes, 2 fragments in landscape xml (A, B) and 1 fragment in portrait xml (only A). When I go to portrait mode in onCreate() of my activity the manager finds fragment B although I thought it should not - my portrait mode xml doesn't have any fragment B, only A. This happens after rotation so I think the manager somehow remembers its old state. That was my first question - is it normal and what to do if I want the manager to have only the fragment I defined for that orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being new to fragments and after struggling a day I think I understood most of the logic behind fragments and their usage. The fact that fragment manager shows fragments other than the ones defined for current orientation is not a bug, it's a feature. Here are some observations summarized:

1. When changing configuration, the `FragmentManager` saves all the fragments it has currently and loads them back so they are ready in `onCreate()` method of container activity. This means that if you have fragment A and B in some layout and you rotate the device to a state where only A should be - you still will find B in `FragmentManager`. It might be not added (check with `Fragment.isAdded()`) or might be added to some other container, which is not visible now, but its there. This is quite useful since B saves its state (given that you did it properly in B's life cycle functions) and you don't have to take care of it on activity level. Maybe, at some point in future, you would like to dynamically add fragment B to your UI and it will have all its state saved from previous configuration.
2. Related to the second question above - fragments that need to be moved from container to container should **not** be declared in xml, they should be added dynamically. Otherwise you will not be able to change its container and will get **IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment** exception. Instead, you define containers in XML file and give them an ID, for example:

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="0.7" />
   ```

   and later add to it using something like

   ```
   FragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
   ```
3. If you need to use some fragment, first look if `FragmentManager` has it - if yes, then just reuse it - it will have its state saved as a bonus. To look for fragment:

   ```
   private void MyFragment getMyFragment() {
       List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
       if (fragments != null) {
           for (Fragment f : fragments) {
               // an example of search criteria
               if (f instanceof MyFragment) {
                   return (MyFragment) f;
               }
           }
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```

   if it is `null` then create a new one, otherwise you can go ahead and reuse it, if needed.
4. One way of reusing a fragment is putting it in another container. You will need some effort in order not to get **IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment**. Here is the code I used with some comments to help understand it:

   ```
   private void moveFragment(MyFragment frag) {
       int targetContainer = R.id.myContainerLandscape;
       // first check if it is added to a correct place
       if (frag.isAdded()) {
           View v = frag.getView();
           if (v != null) {
               int id = ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).getId();
               if (id == targetContainer) {
                   // already added to correct container, skip
                   return;
               }
           }
       }

       FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

       // Remove the fragment from its previous container first (done
       // here without check if added or nor, check if needed).
       // In order not to get 'Can't change container ID...' exception
       // we need to assure several things:
       //   1. its not hardcoded in xml - you can remove()
       //      fragment only if you have add()-ed before
       //   2. if this fragment is sitting deep in a backstack
       //      then you will still get the above mentioned exception.
       //      If the stack is fragA-fragB-fragC <-top then you get
       //      exception on moving fragment A. Need to clean the back
       //      stack first. HOWEVER, note that in that case you will
       //      lose the fragB and fragC together with their states!
       //      For that reason save them first - I will assume there is
       //      only one on top of current fragment to make code simpler.

       // before cleaning save the top fragment so that it is not destroyed
       OtherFragment temp = getOtherFragment(); // use function 'getMyFragment()' above
       // clean the backstack
       manager.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
       // remove the fragment from its current container
       manager.beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();
       // call executePendingTransactions() for your changes to be available
       // right after this call, otherwise the previous 'commit()' just submits
       // the task to main thread and it will be done somewhere in the future
       manager.executePendingTransactions();
       if (getOtherFragment() == null && temp != null) {
           // Add the fragment we wanted to 'save' back to manager, this
           // time without any relation to backstack or container. Later
           // we will be able to find it using getOtherFragment() and the
           // fragment manager will be able to save/load its state for us.
           manager.beginTransaction().add(temp, null).commit();
           manager.executePendingTransactions();
       }

       // now add our fragment
       FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
       transaction.replace(targetContainer, frag);
       transaction.commit();
       manager.executePendingTransactions();
   }
   ```

This was the result of my first day of dealing with fragments seriously, at least my task was accomplished in my app. Would be good to get some comments from experienced guys on what is wrong here and what can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

you can detect if you are on portrait or landscape with this:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
```